# Port forwarding stops working after a while

Tags: macos, ssh, routing, port-forwarding, tcp

Second day in a row I am having a hard time setting up port forwarding on my mac. I was working on a micro service and wanted to utilize through web. I might have messed up some settings, because a while ago I messed around with port forwarding and everything worked just fine. I want my running micro service on `localhost:7171` to be accessible through my public IP address `71.XXX.XX.XXX:9890`.

Here's what I did:

1. I've setup a port forwarding rule on my router and opened a port 9890
2. As per rule all requests are forwarded from `71.XXX.XX.XXX:9890` to `10.0.0.209:9890` (`10.0.0.209` is IPv4 address of my mac)
3. I've setup ssh tunnel to forward `10.0.0.209:9890` to localhost:7171 as `ssh -L 10.0.0.209:9890:localhost:7171 localhost`

What's weird and not good:

1. Once I setup SSH tunnel I can ping my service from web as `71.XXX.XX.XXX:9890`, but only for 10 seconds, afterwards, service doesn't respond, even though it is running and I can hit it locally
2. I can run `10.0.0.209:9890` and still hit my micro service from mac that forwards me to localhost:7171 (SSH tunneling is working, yes!)
3. Another weird thing is that I can't access my micro service if I hit `71.XXX.XX.XXX:9890` from the same wi-fi network, it just hangs and never responds
4. The last thing, which might be normal is that my ssh tunnel dies when I shut down the terminal, tried to use autossh, but again it didn't work

Temporary solutions:

1. Since I have dynamic IP on my phone, I keep reconnecting to internet via LTE and, thus, am able to hit my micro service for another 10 seconds, then it just hangs
2. I played around with ssh config file set different properties, which again didn't help
3. Not a solution: I am about to give up and don't know what the heck is going on.

Please, advice. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In many situations port forwarding doesn't work. I have found this from personal experiences. Actual cause of the failure remains unknown most of the times. Also  many ISPs notoriously close various ports randomly. Port triggering may serve purposes in some cases.
This is not exactly an answer to your problem, I know. Take this as a general purpose comment on the port forwarding problem.
I am not an expert in the field. Please consider my comments very general purpose.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution.